# Display webform result as top list

Tags: webforms

I have a webform where users can choose between nodes on my site. I'm using a Select options component on the webform and dynamically load my node titles with the "Load a pre-built option list" and a custom module to create the list.

I need to display the result of the collected webform data as a top list of the most choosen nodes. The list should look something like:

1. Title of node yy (34 votes)
2. Title of node xx (15 votes)
   ...
3. Title of node zz (0 votes)

I tried using views to display webform submission data and the views aggregation function, but this does not include the nodes that has not gotten any "votes".

Any suggestion of how I could accomplish this would be greatly appreciated!